# Parse unique string from complicated serial data C#

Tags: c#, .net, string, winforms, serial-port

I need to parse this string from serial:-

```
!00037,00055@
```

**00037 as one string, 00055 as another string**

However this string is came out when the robot's tire is rotated and some other string may also display before and after the string that I need to parse. For example this is the some of the transmission received:-

```
11,00085@R-STOPR-STOP!00011,00095@!00001,00015@R-STOP!00001,00085@!00003,00075@!00006,00015@R-STOP!00009,00025@!00011,00035@!00011,00085@R-STOPR-STOP!00011,00095@!00001,00015@R-STOP!00001,00085@!00003,00075@!00006,00015@R-STOP!00009,00025@!00011,00035@R-STOP!00001,00085@!00003,00075@!00006,00015@R-STOP!00009,00025@!00011,00035@R-STOP!00037,00055@!00023,00075@R-STOPR-STOP!00022,00065@!00011,00085@R-STOPR-STOP!00011,00095@!00001,00015@R-STOP!00001,00085@!00003,00075@!00006,00015@R-STOP!00009,00025@!00011,00035@R-STOP!00037,00055@!00023,00075@R-STOPR-STOP!00022,00065@!00011,00085@R-STOPR-STOP!00011,00095@!00001,00015@
```

So far I'm stuck at what to do next after SerialPort.ReadExisting()

Here is some code to retrieve the serial data:-

```
private void serialCom_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        InputData = serialCom.ReadExisting();
        if (InputData != String.Empty)
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new SetTextCallback(IncomingData), new object[] { InputData });
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Error");
    }
}
```

and display incoming serial data inside textbox

```
private void IncomingData(string data)
{           
    tb_incomingData.AppendText(data);
    tb_incomingData.ScrollToCaret();            
}
```

This code is using .NET Framework 4.0 and Windows Form.

Comment: Do you need all the strings that match `!#####,#####@`, or only that one?

Comment: yes @EBrown .. i need all the strings that match !#####,#####@ since it update the rotation of tire

Comment: You could use a regex expression like `!([0-9])+(,[0-9]{5}@)` to trim the strings coming into the serial report. Note: I'm not very good at regex, so there is probably a better way to write that.

Comment: You can never do this with ReadExisting(), you first need to read the *entire* response, then you have a shot at parsing strings.  Maybe you need ReadLine(), maybe ReadTo(), it isn't very clear what to robot uses to indicate the end of the response string.

Comment: @HansPassant He can do this with `ReadExisting()`. All he has to do is keep a running (or rotating) variable with all the string data, and parse out those which he needs.

Comment: @pirates_killer So you only need those that begin with an exclamation point (`!`), have five digits (`#####`), then a comma (`,`), then five more digits (`#####`), then an at symbol (`@`), and you need **all** of them? Also, do you need them as `integers` or as `strings`?

Comment: There is no point in doing this the hard way.

Comment: @HansPassant What's so hard about it? Everytime he does a `ReadExisting()` append it to a `string` variable, and then throw that `string` to a function that parses out any instances of `!#####,#####@`. If it finds one (and with as fast as it'd be, it'd likely either find one or none) then truncate the string to that point so it can continue without much issue for overflow.

Comment: @ShawnicHedgehog I saw it earlier also, it is my first time looking at regex.. but it might look promising..

Comment: @HansPassant the robot will always send the string, there are lot of strings not included here but inside the many strings contain the one that I need every time the robot moves. The strings always have different structures.

Comment: @EBrown the function of '!' and '@' just to help splitting it. I tried the method of appending to the string until it found '!' and split the value accordingly. Using this method to get the values [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) but I fail to clear the appended string since it involve try{} catch{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solve it using indexof and substring.

```
private void IncomingData(string data)
{
  //Show received data in textbox
  tb_incomingData.AppendText(data);
  tb_incomingData.ScrollToCaret();

  //Append data inside longdata (string)
  longData = longData + data;
  if (longData.Contains('@') && longData.Contains(',') && longData.Contains('!')) 
  {
    try
    {
      indexSeru = longData.IndexOf('!'); //retrieve index number of the symbol !
      indexComma = longData.IndexOf(','); //retrieve index number of the symbol ,
      indexAlias = longData.IndexOf('@'); //retrieve index number of the symbol ,
      rotation = longData.Substring(indexSeru + 1, 5); //first string is taken after symbol ! and 5 next char
      subRotation = longData.Substring(indexComma + 1, 5); //second string is taken after symbol ! and 5 next char
      //tss_distance.Text = rotation + "," + subRotation;
      longData = null; //clear longdata string      
    }
    catch
    {
      indexSeru = 0;
      indexComma = 0;
      indexAlias = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can determine your pattern to transform this string into a array using SPLIT function.

This code, send "!00037,00055@" returns two itens: 00037 and 00055.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string k = "!00037,00055@";
        var array = k.ToString().Split(',');
        Console.WriteLine("Dirty Itens");
        for (var x = 0; x <= array.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            var linha = "Item " + x.ToString() + " = " + array[x];
            Console.WriteLine(linha);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Cleaned Itens");
        for (var x = 0; x <= array.Length - 1; x++)
        {
            var linha = "Item " + x.ToString() + " = " + CleanString(array[x]);
            Console.WriteLine(linha);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();

    }

    public static string CleanString(string inputString)
    {
        string resultString = "";
        Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"[^\d]");
        resultString = regexObj.Replace(inputString, "");
        return resultString;            
    }
```

Comment: He's asking about how to get that string though, from the incoming serial data.